# Data Migration from Azure SQL Databases to Dynamics 365 for Marketing using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, dynamics-365, azure-data-factory

I want to migrate data from Azure SQL Database(around 100 databases) to Dynamics 365 for marketing using Azure Data Factory. As I am new to Azure, I have several questions regarding this.

1. Is this possible to copy from such large number of databases to Dynamics 365 for Marketing?
2. I have several tables and long list of columns from databases, but I want to move only some data to Dynamics 365. Is it possible to create related records in CRM and assign them to the primary entity using Azure Data Factory?
3. Can anyone explain me what needs to be done in order to achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

that is a very big question, let's break it down a bit:

- Q: Does Azure Data Factory support Azure SQL and Dynamics 365
- A: Yes. both are supported as a source and a sink (target) data store. The list of supported connectors [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview)
- Q: Can you import data from multiple databases and sources
- A: Sure, but you need to be a bit clever.
  Some tools and techniques that will help:

  1. Use the Data Factory [loop](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/matthow/post/Using-Lookup-Execute-Pipeline-and-For-Each-Activity-in-Azure-Data-Factory-V2) construct
  2. Use [Azure ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template) to help set up your database connections (you can write some simple code to automatically generate all the relevant linked services)
  3. Use queries to shape the data you want to import. Look for sqlReaderQuery in [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)
- Q: Is it possible to create related records in CRM and assign them to the primary entity using Azure Data Factory?
- A: I don't think this is possible. You are limited to what the connector will do for you. Look for the "Sink" section in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365) to see what the connector can do. An alternative is to write your own [custom activity](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/ADFv2CustomActivitySample) that does sink, and then you have full control over the behaviour.

Hope that gets you started!